# Visualize and calculate how many rectangles/squares can fit in a larger rectangle (update: Bin Packing)

Tags: javascript, html, css, algorithm, bin-packing

I need to create an a function that calculate how many rectangles/squares of given/fixed width and height fit into a larger rectangle of fixed width and height. The orientation should not matter. The objective is best use the space with the given sizes.

Here is what I tried: https://codepen.io/mzmarkib/pen/vYXbayY

Edit/Update: I tried another approach using a library called [Shelf-pack](https://github.com/mapbox/shelf-pack)
but still having blank spaces, don't konw what I'm doing wrong. please take a look:
[CodePen Link](https://codepen.io/mzmarkib/pen/KKgJEGo)

**HTML**

```
<div class="plate"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}
.plate {
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin: auto;
}
.page {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  float: left;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
//sizes for pages(blue rectangles)
let pages = {
  a3: { w: 29.7, h: 42 },
  a4: { w: 21, h: 29.7 },
  custom: { w: 33, h: 20 },
  custom: { w: 5, h: 5 }
};

const PLATE_SIZE = { w: 100, h: 70 }; //demesions of the plate (red rectangle)
const SCALE = 10; //scale for representation

const plate = document.querySelector(".plate");
plate.style.width = PLATE_SIZE.w * SCALE + "px";
plate.style.height = PLATE_SIZE.h * SCALE + "px";
const plate_boundary = plate.getBoundingClientRect();

//Adds a page(blue rectangle) to the plate(red rectangle), then checks whether it's out of bounds, if yes removes the page(blue rectangle) and returns false
function addPage(w, h, name) {
  page = document.createElement("div");
  page.innerHTML = name;
  page.classList.add("page");
  page.style.width = w * SCALE + "px";
  page.style.height = h * SCALE + "px";

  plate.appendChild(page);

  if (!isWithinBoundary(page)) {
    plate.removeChild(page);
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
//check if a page(blue rectangle) is out of bounds
function isWithinBoundary(page) {
  const rect = page.getBoundingClientRect();
  return (
    rect.top >= 0 &&
    rect.left >= 0 &&
    rect.bottom <= plate_boundary.bottom &&
    rect.right <= plate_boundary.right
  );
}
//recursively add pages to the plate (red rectangle)
function fillPages(pages) {
  for (const page in pages) {
    const { w, h } = pages[page];
    while (addPage(w, h, page)) {
      continue;
    }
    while (addPage(h, w, page)) {
      continue;
    }
  }
}

fillPages(pages); //execution
```

With my approach it not filling rectangles in certain areas even though there is blank space.

Please forgive me if this is a stupid question. If not please guide me how to approach this problem. Either way thanks in advance...

Comment: Discussions on [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4386/tiling-posters-on-a-wall/4388#4388) or search for [`bin packing`](https://cgi.csc.liv.ac.uk/~epa/surveyhtml.html)

Comment: you need to set a height and width for plates in "px" in order to be fixed height and width

Comment: @pilchard thanks it helped, I tried another approach using a library called [Shelf-pack][2]
 but still having blank spaces, don't konw what I'm doing wrong. please take a look:
[CodePen Link][1]

Comment: The shelf pack actually does everything it promised to do - it separates the rectangle into shelves of a fixed width and fills each shelf with the content. (First page of their documentation.) It does no further attempts to split a shelf with an already fixed width.

Comment: @Shamis yes you are correct, I checked other libraries for bin packing, they all do the packing well, but they do not have methods to see if a rectangle fits within the rectangle before packing it.

Comment: You could use the shelf-pack library to do the first-round of packing since it works reasonably well. Then you could manually extract the unpacked space(A bit of analytical geometry) and call the library once more. The issue is that for the general case, the packing is a **hard** problem. (As in NP-hard) so there is no fast & clean algorithmic solution, only heuristics or bruteforce. Your case could be easy enough to get close-to-optimal with a custom heuristic.